# This should be clear

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall

The set of sixteen words below can be partitioned. Each partition is of four words that have something in common. I invite you to figure out the partitions and commonalities. You'll find that the four commonalities have, themselves, something in common.

AWAY, BRINGS, DEATH, DESCRIES, ENDS, KNOWLEDGE, MEMORIES, NIGHT, QUANDARY, SINGS, SLEEP, SOLDIERS, STARS, THOUGHTS, VERSION, WAKES

Hint, added later:  I considered tagging this

> [poetry](/questions/tagged/poetry).  But then I read its description ("Puzzles that are presented in the form of any of the various types of poetry.") and realized it's inapplicable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 4 groups are *clearly* (!) intended to be resolved as follows:

**Group 1**

> AWAY, VERSION, ENDS, QUANDARY
>
>  These are one-word titles of poems in [Robert Frost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Frost)'s 1962 collection, [**In the *Clear*ing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Clearing).

**Group 2**

> NIGHT, SLEEP, DEATH, STARS
>
>  These words all appear in the last line of [Walt Whitman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walt_Whitman)'s short poem, [**A *Clear* Midnight**](https://poets.org/poem/clear-midnight):
>
>  *This is thy hour O Soul, thy free flight into the wordless,*
>  *Away from books, away from art, the day erased, the lesson done,*
>  *Thee fully forth emerging, silent, gazing, pondering the themes thou lovest best,*
>  ***Night, sleep, death and the stars.***

**Group 3**

> MEMORIES, SOLDIERS, THOUGHTS, KNOWLEDGE
>
>  Four words which follow 'no' in the [Wallace Stevens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_Stevens) poem, [**A *Clear* Day and No Memories**](https://hellopoetry.com/poem/14547/a-clear-day-and-no-memories/):
>
>  ***No soldiers** in the scenery,*
>  ***No thoughts** of people now dead,*
>  *As they were fifty years ago,*
>  *Young and living in a live air,*
>  *Young and walking in the sunshine,*
>  *Bending in blue dresses to touch something,*
>  *Today the mind is not part of the weather.*
>
>  *Today the air is clear of everything.*
>  *It has **no knowledge** except of nothingness*
>  *And it flows over us without meanings,*
>  *As if none of us had ever been here before*
>  *And are not now: in this shallow spectacle,*
>  *This invisible activity, this sense.*
>
>  NB '**No Memories**' appears in the title!

**Group 4**

> DESCRIES, WAKES, SINGS, BRINGS
>
>  Four verbs which appear in the [Robert Louis Stevenson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Louis_Stevenson) poem, [**The Cock's *Clear* Voice Into the *Clear* Air**](https://www.poetryloverspage.com/poets/stevenson/cocks_clear_voice.html):
>
>  Line 6: *The coming morn **descries**,*
>  Line 7: *And, mankind's bugler, **wakes***
>  Line 9: *He **sings** the morn upon the westward hills*
>  Line 11: *He **sings** it in the land*
>  Line 13: *He **brings** to me dear voices of the past,*

And in case it isn't *clear* by now, all four groups are connected by:

> the appearance of the word '**CLEAR**' within a poem, its title or its collection!

Comment: How did you?!?!

Comment: @Deepthinker101 A hunch from the hint, and a lot of Google to pinpoint the right ones! :) I'd been thinking about this one on and off for a few days and actually stumbled upon one of these in the process, but just didn't spot the connection until tonight!

Comment: Bravo!! In group 4, it's not just words that appear rot13(va gur cbrz: vg'f npgvbaf gung gur pbpx gnxrf, nf qrfpevorq va gur cbrz).

Comment: @msh210 Indeed - I stuck with 'verbs' so as not to need to resurrect my school exam days and delve deeper still! Thanks for the bounty :) This was a deceptively tricky connect-wall! I had no idea where I would end up when I began, and I had a very interesting tour of some great works along the way...

Comment: Criminally underrated (like many on PSE)! I remembered being gobsmacked by the solution. I am not saying this digital currency is really worth anything in the end of the day, but it is crazy how this only got 5 upvotes considering how many imho very mediocre answers have got at least double this!